# How to create several files based on Netbeans' templates into different packages at once?

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, javafx

I have a little Problem with Netbeans templates. At the moment I am only able to create one file at a time from a Netbeans template. But what I want to do is:

Pick a template and let Netbeans create all needed files at once similar to the javafx fxml template with the difference that I want the files in different packages and I want more files.

Is it possible to edit the existing fxml file creation template ?

I already searched the web and I came up with some ideas but i don't think they will help me as I don't want a sampleproject template or stuff like that. I was thinking about a own netbeans wizard but i am not sure if that will help me and the netbeans tutorials are not helpful enough.

Someone asked a similar question on SO last year ([how-to-make-netbeans-templates-that-creates-more-than-1-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157043)) with the difference that he wanted to edit a template to create 5 instead of 4 xhtml files

> My question is how can I make or change a template like "JSF Pages
>   From Entity Beans" that generates not only 1 file, but 4 for each
>   entity. So I can change this template to generate 5 files

The current fxml file dialog creates the fxml file and a the java control class into same package. I could manually move the controller to another package but as the controller path is mentioned in the fxml file and refactor doesn't apply to it, i have to manually change the path each time.

Next Problem is that I have more than the fxml file and the control class I need to create. The following screenshot demonstrates the result i need to accomplish:

[screenshotlink (i am not allowed to include an image sorry)](http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/5989/exampleds.png)

I have templates for each filetype (the fxml, the fxmlcontrol and the fxmlpresenter). But i would like to combine them into one new file dialog option to reduce the manual work and possible mistakes like different names etc.