# Netbeans Template that creates multiple files

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2, freemarker, wizard

Generally speaking I want to create a Netbeans (7.4) File Wizard that creates multiple files.

In my case I want it to create JavaFX related files to use a convention over configuration approach when loading fxml files. (I took that Idea from Adam Bien: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mawFd4h1Or4)

More Specific: I want to enter a single String that defines a `Basename` and want the wizard to create 3 different files, located in the package where the Rightclick -> "New" wizard was invoked by the user.

1. `Basename.fxml`
2. `BasenameController.java`
3. `BasenameView.java`

I tried to write my own Wizard for almost 3 days now, and it won't work. I have studied the (thin) Netbeans API and read all these tutorials (and more) carefully:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/multiple_files_from_a_single
- https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html
- http://code-chimpanzee-at-large.blogspot.de/2012/09/netbeans-71-file-template-module-with.html
- https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-wizard.html

I tried more things then i can enumerate here, but these are some of the things that keep happining:

- I never got it to work with a single `@TemplateRegistration` and multiple `content` entries.
- So I registered multiple templates with `@TemplateRegistrations`, one Template for each file I wanted to create.
- This creates multiple files, but only the first file has correct properties like ${package} set for the freemarker script. (Additionally this way I end up with multiple Templates ... but I could live with that.)
- Then I tried to use other poperty names and set these by hand, But I can't figure out how to find the package the wizard was invoked on.

Related Questions, which did not really help me:

- [how-to-create-several-files-based-on-netbeans-templates-into-different-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377314/how-to-create-several-files-based-on-netbeans-templates-into-different-packages)
- [how-to-make-netbeans-templates-that-creates-more-than-1-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157043/how-to-make-netbeans-templates-that-creates-more-than-1-file)

Any advice is very welcome. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I managed to create the desired files. The problem was that you **have** to use a sparsely documented naming convention. If you want to correctly create a `Basename.java` file, you have to name the template file: `Basename.java` (which makes your compiler unhappy, as the template file is not a valid java class), or **`Basename.java.template`**. If you name it anything else like: `Basename.java.templ` (and manage the correct naming of the file yourself), it will not set the `${package}` variable for you.

So now I'm very close to what I wanted, but there is still a problem left with correctly registering the Wizard.

Currently I'm using `@TemplateRegistrations` to register 3 templates (one for each file). But as the "folder" attribute is mandatory I now have 3 entries in the "New" Wizard of Netbeans. When i invoke one of them it will create all 3 files as desired, but I would like to only have 1 entry in the "New" Wizard.

```
@TemplateRegistrations({
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "FXML.fxml.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial", displayName = "#TemplateName", iconBase = "de/ekrnrw/fxmlview/view.png", description = "newFXMLView.html"),
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "View.java.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial"),
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "Controller.java.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial")
})
```

I tried to use a single `@TemplateRegistration` with multiple content entries, but this does not work with the code from the tutorial. It seems like only the fxml file is processed be freemarker, and the two java files are being just plain copies of the template files.

```
@TemplateRegistration(content = {"FXML.fxml.template","View.java.template","Controller.java.template"}, scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial", displayName = "#TemplateName", iconBase = "de/ekrnrw/fxmlview/view.png", description = "newFXMLView.html")
```

I posted this question to the NetBeans mailing list [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic59082.html). And here is the relevant code snippet:

```
package de.ekrnrw.fxmlview;

import java.awt.Component;
...
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@TemplateRegistrations({
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "FXML.fxml.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial", displayName = "#TemplateName", iconBase = "de/ekrnrw/fxmlview/view.png", description = "newFXMLView.html"),
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "View.java.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial"),
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "Controller.java.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial")
})

// Would like to use this, but i can't make it work.
//@TemplateRegistration(content = {"FXML.fxml.template","View.java.template","Controller.java.template"}, scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial", displayName = "#TemplateName", iconBase = "de/ekrnrw/fxmlview/view.png", description = "newFXMLView.html")

@Messages("TemplateName=FXMLView4")

public final class NewFXMLViewWizardIterator implements WizardDescriptor.InstantiatingIterator<WizardDescriptor> {

    private int index;

    private WizardDescriptor wizard;
    private List<WizardDescriptor.Panel<WizardDescriptor>> panels;

    private List<WizardDescriptor.Panel<WizardDescriptor>> getPanels() {
        if (panels == null) {
            panels = new ArrayList<>();

            // Change to default new file panel and add our panel at bottom
            Project p = Templates.getProject(wizard);
            SourceGroup[] groups = ProjectUtils.getSources(p).getSourceGroups(Sources.TYPE_GENERIC);

            // SimpleTargetChooser is the default new file panel
            WizardDescriptor.Panel<WizardDescriptor> advNewFilePanel = Templates.buildSimpleTargetChooser(p, groups).create();
            panels.add(advNewFilePanel);

            String[] steps = createSteps();
            for (int i = 0; i < panels.size(); i++) {
                Component c = panels.get(i).getComponent();
                if (steps[i] == null) {
                    // Default step name to component name of panel. Mainly
                    // useful for getting the name of the target chooser to
                    // appear in the list of steps.
                    steps[i] = c.getName();
                }
                if (c instanceof JComponent) { // assume Swing components
                    JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
                    jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_SELECTED_INDEX, i);
                    jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_DATA, steps);
                    jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_AUTO_WIZARD_STYLE, true);
                    jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_DISPLAYED, true);
                    jc.putClientProperty(WizardDescriptor.PROP_CONTENT_NUMBERED, true);
                }
            }
        }
        return panels;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<?> instantiate() throws IOException {

        //Get the folder:
        FileObject dir = Templates.getTargetFolder(wizard);
        DataFolder df = DataFolder.findFolder(dir);

        //Get TargetName from File Wizard
        String targetName = Templates.getTargetName(wizard);

        // Read Title from wizard 
        String viewName = targetName + "View";
        String controllerName = targetName + "Controller";

        // FreeMarker Template will get its variables from HashMap.
        // HashMap key is the variable name.
        Map args = new HashMap();
        args.put("controllerName", controllerName);
        args.put("viewName", viewName);

        //Get Templates
        FileObject[] templates = Templates.getTemplate(wizard).getParent().getChildren();

        // Create all Files
        Set<DataObject> createdObjects = new HashSet<>();

        for (FileObject fileObject : templates) {

            DataObject dTemplate = DataObject.find(fileObject);
            String templateName = dTemplate.getName();

            // Sepcial treatment for the .fxml file.
            if (templateName.equals("FXML")) {
                templateName = "";
            }

            // Create file
            createdObjects.add(dTemplate.createFromTemplate(df, targetName + templateName , args));
        }
        return createdObjects;
    }    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to display only one entry per template ?

Answer (score 1):

Please ask at the mailing list dev@platform.netbeans.org and provide a non-working sample, so that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there. I updated my Question because I managed to solve one part of my Problem. This time with code ;).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your sample and I looked it up. You are not required to use the @TemplateRegistration annotation to use freemarker nor to use `Templates.getTemplate(wizard).getParent().getChildren()`

1. Get each of your templates via

   `FileObject template1 = FileUtil.getConfigFile("CustomerSalesTemplates/project1.txt");
   DataObject dTemplate1 = DataObject.find(template1);`
2. and then use
   `dTemplate1.createFromTemplate` to invoke freemarker

See the articles
* https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/how_to_visually_diff_multiple 
* https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/freemarker_baked_into_netbeans_ide1

Comment: Hm, but I still need to register the WizardIterator somehow, because otherwise it will not show up in the "New File" Wizard of Netbeans, or am I missing something?

Comment: You can try to register only template via annotations, so that you still have the wizard integration. But the other instanciated templates you create via the code above

Answer (score 0):

All `@TemplateRegistration` annotations will be converted into file entries in a file called `layer.xml` at build time. In `layer.xml`, file templates are presented as follows:

```
<filesystem>
    <folder name="Templates">
        <folder name="javafx">
            <file name="FxmlNode.java" url="nbresloc:/tuupertunut/fxmltemplates/FxmlNode.java.template">
                <attr name="template" boolvalue="true"/>
                <attr name="displayName" bundlevalue="tuupertunut.fxmltemplates.Bundle#FxmlNode_displayName"/>
                <attr name="iconBase" stringvalue="org/netbeans/spi/java/project/support/ui/templates/class.png"/>
                <attr name="instantiatingWizardURL" urlvalue="nbresloc:/tuupertunut/fxmltemplates/FxmlNodeDescription.html"/>
                <attr name="instantiatingIterator" newvalue="tuupertunut.fxmltemplates.FxmlNodeIterator"/>
                <attr name="requireProject" boolvalue="true"/>
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
            </file>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</filesystem>
```

You can see a `file` entry that has `attr` attributes. The relevant attributes regarding your question are `template` and `javax.script.ScriptEngine`.

- Every `file` entry that has `<attr name="template"
  boolvalue="true"/>` will be shown as a separate entry in the "New
  file" dialog.
- Every `file` entry that has `<attr
  name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>` will be
  processed by freemarker before creating the file.

---

## Case 1: Multiple `@TemplateRegistration`s

```
@TemplateRegistrations({
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "FXML.fxml.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial", ...),
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "View.java.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial"),
    @TemplateRegistration(content = "Controller.java.template", scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial")
})
```

will convert to

```
<filesystem>
    <folder name="Templates">
        <folder name="ASpecial">
            <file name="FXML.fxml" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/FXML.fxml.template">
                <attr name="template" boolvalue="true"/>
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
                ...
            </file>
            <file name="View.java" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/View.java.template">
                <attr name="template" boolvalue="true"/>
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
                ...
            </file>
            <file name="Controller.java" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/Controller.java.template">
                <attr name="template" boolvalue="true"/>
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
                ...
            </file>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</filesystem>
```

As you can see, all three templates will show in the "New file" dialog and all three templates will be processed by freemarker.

---

## Case 2: Multiple `content` in single `@TemplateRegistration`

```
@TemplateRegistration(content = {"FXML.fxml.template","View.java.template","Controller.java.template"}, scriptEngine = "freemarker", folder = "ASpecial", ...)
```

will convert to

```
<filesystem>
    <folder name="Templates">
        <folder name="ASpecial">
            <file name="FXML.fxml" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/FXML.fxml.template">
                <attr name="template" boolvalue="true"/>
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
                ...
            </file>
            <file name="View.java" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/View.java.template">
                ...
            </file>
            <file name="Controller.java" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/Controller.java.template">
                ...
            </file>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</filesystem>
```

Here only the first template will show in the "New file" dialog and also only the first will be processed by freemarker.

---

## Solution

As the annotations won't produce the desired `layer.xml`, you must create one yourself. You should be able to find the automatically generated `generated-layer.xml` from your project's `build/classes/META-INF` directory. Create a new `layer.xml` file for your project from the "New file" dialog and copy-paste everything into it. Then you can edit those `template` and `javax.script.ScriptEngine` attributes by hand.

In the end, it should look something like this:

```
<filesystem>
    <folder name="Templates">
        <folder name="ASpecial">
            <file name="FXML.fxml" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/FXML.fxml.template">
                <attr name="template" boolvalue="true"/>
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
                ...
            </file>
            <file name="View.java" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/View.java.template">
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
                ...
            </file>
            <file name="Controller.java" url="nbresloc:/yourpackage/Controller.java.template">
                <attr name="javax.script.ScriptEngine" stringvalue="freemarker"/>
                ...
            </file>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</filesystem>
```

Where the first entry is the only one with `template` but all of them have `javax.script.ScriptEngine`

Don't forget to remove your `@TemplateRegistration` annotations, as the templates are now managed by your `layer.xml`.